# Dynamic Piping in C

Tags: pipe, exec

there. Is there anyone know any easy way to implement piping in C based on user input. For example, a user may give **"ls | grep .c | wc"** or might give **"ls | grep .c"**. I want the program to tokenize based on | and complete that. It needs to use fork, exec. Looking for an simple approach.